# Winter grease for extreme cold temperatures

Tags: hub, lubricant

I'm using a fat bike rear hub (Sun Ringle). It malfunctioned twice in less than a month riding everyday in winter ❄️. It stopped turning at all so I had it serviced but then it stopped again when it got down to -37°C.

I do not know the exact causes other than grease durability of parts etc. Could this because I didn't use a winter-specific grease, or would it be indicative of a manufacturing or quality problem with the hub?

Comment: In what way did your hub malfunction? The freewheel stopped working? The whole thing stopped turning? Something else? Also, what exactly is your question, here? Are you asking if there are greases appropriate to these temperatures? If the grease is likely to be the problem? For a product recommendation? (Note that we don't do product recommendations as they tend to be location-specific and often go out of date.)

Comment: Thanks David  the rear hub stopped turning  re-serviced but stopped working again at minus 37 C Is all these problems happening because I did not used a specific Winter Grease or bad manufacturing of The Sun Ringle Rear Hub ?

Comment: Thanks -- that's much clearer. I edited the extra information into your question, which is the best way to get people to see it. (Comments are really only intended to be temporary.) By the way, did the shop who serviced it know that you intended to use the bike in such cold temperatures? They might have already used a low-temperature grease.

Answer (score 3):

I use Agrinol 158, which works down to -50°C. It's a blue color. It is an automotive lithium-based grease and I do not think it was specifically tested for bicycle applications; however, at -37°C it does not matter really as long as it works for someone. The "NLGI 1;2" on the can refers to the [NLGI consistency number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLGI_consistency_number)  meaning it is a "soft" grease with medium viscosity. Maybe you can find an analog where you are.

[image]

Comment: Is this a bicycle specific lube or something that you might find in an auto parts store? What is it normally sold as (purpose)? Can you use it everywhere you’d normally use bike grease? What is it’s maximum temperature - should it be replaced in the spring?

Comment: There's nothing magic about bikes that need special grease. On contrary, the speeds are low, loads light and temperatures never above ambient. Any grease with low enough temperature limit should work.